# Как настроить несколько SSH ключей для github.com и gitlab.com

Tags: git, github, gitlab

### **UPD Вопрос решен. В поле user не указал "git".**

---

Всех приветствую!

У меня есть несколько репозиториев, два личных, они лежат на github.com, сейчас жизнь привела к тому, что мне требуется репозиторий на gitlab.com.

Раньше я пользовался несколькими репо на одной машине, используя несколько ssh-ключей и конфиг вида:

```
host gh-acc1
hostname github.com
user git
identityfile key1

host gh-acc2
hostname github.com
user git
identityfile key2
```

Сейчас вздумалось повторить сей фокус и для того, чтобы пользоваться гитлабом.

Добавил в конфигурацию

```
# Gitlab 
Host acc3
  HostName git.mycompany.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/evgenii
```

Проверяю

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
```

Есть ответ, здавствуй, $user

Однако, при попытке запушить репозиторий через

```
git push acc3:test/test_project.git
```

Получаю

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Попробовал запушить топором

```
 git push https://git.mycompany.com/test/test_project.git
```

Все хорошо.

Вопрос к знатокам, в чем может быть дело, почему я не могу получить доступ по ssh таким образом? Аналогичный способ конфигурирования прекрасно работает с github и я пользуюсь несколькими аккаунтами.

Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Добавьте в секцию с гилабом `IdentitiesOnly yes`. Что-то такое было у меня: у вас много ключей, ssh пробует их все, gitlab отказывает из-за большого числа попыток. Ключ, что я написал, снижает количество обращений. https://superuser.com/questions/268776/how-do-i-configure-ssh-so-it-doesnt-try-all-the-identity-files-automatically

Comment: А почему в конфигурации acc3 отсутствует аналогичный `user git`?

Comment: @andreymal, да, мой факап! благодарю :) вопрос закрыт! надеюсь, по поисковой выдаче он будет полезен тем, кто захочет так же настроить несколько SSH для работы с разными сервисами

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за информацию, приму к сведению!